# Rails Routes Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Did the rules for Rails Routes changes from Rails 1.2.3 to Rails 2.2.3? I recently upgraded an application and instead of redirecting to the correct page, it now redirects to the main page (or Route page) for that matter.

The only thing that I can think of is that the routing rules changed in Rails 2.2.3.

Thanks

Comment: can you post some code to provide context for this?

Comment: map.connect 'file/do_the_upload', :controller => 'file', :action => 'do_the_upload'

this redirects to / instead of doing the upload

Answer (score 5):

Yep there were a lot of changes as you can see [here](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2007/9/30/rails-2-0-0-preview-release) (look at the Action Pack Resources section) *"This is where the bulk of the action for 2.0 has gone*". If you're using the old semi-colon syntax then that could well be the problem. Do you want to post your route config and a quick description of what is not working?

Also, to diagnose routing problems I find running "rake routes" very useful (though set your terminal window to wide).

Chris